# Savescumming in XCOM 2

Tags: xcom-2

Does the seed generated that determines whether or not you hit an enemy, get a successful hack (with a bonus hack reward), or dodging overwatch fire) generate after you move or before you move, and is it random every time?

In XCOM: EU, savescumming was possible so long as you didn't move, as the seed was generated upon squad movement, and thus it was possible to reload saves over and over to get the desired outcome. Does the same hold true of XCOM 2?

Comment: Do you have a source to confirm that?  XCOM:EU had a "second wave" option to change the seed on every reload, but I've never heard anyone claim "the seed is generated upon squad movement"... That wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: When you move withing the squad member's defined range to move, and for example, try to capture an alien, the seed generated that would allow you to capture is generated every time you do so.  I know this anecdotally since I remember getting 85% chance to capture at close range, saving the game, loading it, and every time it would fail, even after 50 tries.

Comment: This article references the exact same thing http://www.popmatters.com/post/165288-/, as does http://www.pcgamesn.com/secret-dice-rolls-xcom-enemy-within

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You should know that it wasn't XCOM:EU that added a second wave option, but XCOM:EW that added the feature.

Comment: None of those links (nor your anecdote) support your claim though.  They all agree with me: the seed is generated at the start of the mission, and saved in the save file, regardless of whether you have moved.   So I don't see how you could "get the desired outcome" by saving before your move?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The premise of your question is incorrect.

> In XCOM: EU, savescumming was possible so long as you didn't move, as the seed was generated upon squad movement, and thus it was possible to reload saves over and over to get the desired outcome.

This is false.  The seed is generated at the start of the battle - it has nothing to do with whether or not you've moved.  Doing the same actions in the same order would always cause the same outcomes, so the method of save-scumming you mention would not have worked.

However, it *is* still possible to save-scum in XCOM:EU by taking different actions.  For example, if unit A misses their shot, reload, have unit B do something, then try the shot again with unit A.  This method of save-scumming still works in XCOM 2.

For more info, see the [Random vs Seed](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Random_vs_Seed_%28XCOM:_Enemy_Unknown%29) article on the XCOM:EU wiki.

---

It's also worth mentioning that XCOM:EW added a "second wave" option called [Save Scum](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Second_Wave#Default_2), which generated the seed on every reload.  Using this option, if a unit misses a shot you can simply reload and try again.

In XCOM 2, there are two mods that do the same thing.  [One](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=621237465) works automatically, but is written in a way that makes it incompatible with a lot of other mods; [the other](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=620450319) restores compatibility at the cost of having to click a button.

Comment: I've been playing all weekend, and this seems to be correct. If I perform the same actions in the same order after a load I seem to get the same results.

Comment: I noticed that if I reload and try a hack again, the bar stops at a different spot every time. It seems like the success or failure is set though. The bar might just be a graphic that is generated after the fact, rather than actually showing the random number rolled for the hack.

Comment: Let me add that the second mod in the answer is outdated; it no longer works, and no longer updated. [Here's a fork of that mod](http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/filedetails/?id=852360493) that actually works (with pointers on how to make it work in WotC)

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that the seed that gets saved in a save game is different than the one you had the first time.  Here's what happened to me:

1. Beginning of turn, specialist successfully hacks a tower, giving the entire squad re-stealth (iirc 54% chance)
2. Moved another soldier.  During the move, the game froze up to where I had to ctrl-alt-delete.
3. Reload from auto-save
4. Specialist can no longer successfully hack the tower.  I spent over an hour trying different combinations of move this soldier here, move that solder there, going into the next turn even, specialist could NOT hack the tower again to save her life.  After dozens of re-loads, I finally gave up and proceeded with the mission without the tower bonus.

Comment: This might be related to whatever caused the game to freeze. I was messing around with reloading after hacks when trying to do everything perfect for the Exquisite Timing achievement, and every load produced the same hack results (although the bar graphic changed). If you want to get the hack, you can do take a shot (moving a soldier doesn't do anything), save, and try again.